# PHP redirecting all paths to a certain php file?

Tags: php, redirect

Let's say I have a main folder in my website named "test" which contains an index.php file
www.example.com/test/index.php

How can I make it so that any url which contains this path "www.example.com/test" redirects to "www.example.com/test/index.php" and still hold the first request path

for example:

```
www.example.com/test/User       redirects to www.example.com/test/index.php
www.example.com/test/User/2     redirects to www.example.com/test/index.php
www.example.com/test/Account    redirects to www.example.com/test/index.php
www.example.com/test/Account/5  redirects to www.example.com/test/index.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Apache's [Rewrite module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/).  For example, in a virtual-hosts config, or in a directory's `.htaccess` file, you might write this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This would make any URL that approached that directory redirect to `index.php` but it would not change the URL the script parses.

---

Here are some Godaddy.com docs on using rewrites in their hosting environment:

- [What is mod_rewrite?](http://help.godaddy.com/article/898)
- [How do I use mod_rewrite?](http://help.godaddy.com/article/899)

Comment: Thanks, I am using godaddy, any idea where i can find "httpd.config" ?