# mod_rewrite redirect all requests to index.php, including directories

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect all requests to index.php.

Such as: `localhost/abc/def` ---> `localhost/index.php?url=abc/def`

Here's my .htaccess line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But I have a problem, I have a directory "test", when I go to `localhost/test`, I want it to redirect to `locahost/index.php?url=test`, but the address bar reads `localhost/test/?url=test`.

How can I remove the query string? (`?url=test` or something like this when I entered address which access to directory)?

Comment: Have you tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800768/php-redirecting-all-pathes-to-a-certain-php-file ?

Answer (score 3):

It is because `mod_dir` runs after your rewrite rule and adds a redirect to add trailing slash.

You can have this in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: +1! I wondered why it seemed to be doing both the rewrite and a redirect!